# Finding two middle values in R?

Tags: r

EDIT: the output is : [1] 49 65. Only allowed to use INDEXING. Code cannot be hard coded.
Can anyone please provide the code in R for finding two middle values in a vector with 10 elements?
The code would need to work for any vector size. so it cannot be hardcoded
The elements are 59,46,76,60,49,65,82,68,99,52

Comment: Do you want the middle elements from the sorted numeric vector, or just the middle indices? What is your expected output if the input vector has an odd number of elements?

Comment: You could use the `median` function but it averages the middle two values for an even-length list.

Comment: @acvill It must not be sorted .Must be as is. The output is [1] 49 65. Only allowed to use INDEXING. Must not be hard coded, so if more elements are added later on, the code must still work without any change in the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- c(59,46,76,60,49,65,82,68,99,52) 
 
 if(length(x)%%2 == 0) {
   x[c(length(x)/2,(length(x)/2+1))]
 } else{
   x[ceiling(length(x)/2)]
 }
[1] 49 65
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a vector `array` with our values

```
array <- c(59,46,76,60,49,65,82,68,99,52)
```

From left to right, the middle two values of this array are the 5th and 6th

```
array[5:6]
# 49 65
```

If we want the numerically 5th and 6th highest number we can go with

```
sort(array)[5:6]
# 60 65
```

If you want to know which position of the original array the middle two elements are in, you can do

```
which(array %in% sort(array)[5:6])
# 4 6
```

You can expand the above programmatically for any array of even length by doing

```
n <- length(array)
x <- n/2
y <- x  + 1
```

Then in any of the previous three examples, just replace 5 by `x` and 6 by `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```
x <- c(59,46,76,60,49,65,82,68,99,52)

c(x[length(x)/2],x[length(x)/2 + 1])
```